# Facebook Restful API create reaction

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm looking to create a facebook reaction (like/etc) using just the authenticated user token and a URL without using the SDK.  I keep reading that the API is RESTful, however, I can't get any information on this aspect of it.  From this API reference link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/object/likes/

it seems I can post a "like", but I don't see any information anywhere about the full spectrum of reactions (sad/angry/etc).  The docs say that if a reaction has already been given by the user than posting a like won't change it - but it doesn't indicate how I would post a reaction other than "like".  Simply put, my questions are: is it possible and if so, how?

Comment: What does "create a facebook reaction (like/etc)" mean?

Comment: If I have an app that is showing some facebook content, like a post, and the user of my app has logged in to facebook through my app, then I would like to provide a link for them to create a like/love/haha/wow/sad/angry of the post they are viewing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is not currently exposed

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/reactions

> Creating
>
> You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.